# IRetryAnalyzer HELP, can't make it work

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm new on this so this isn't so obvious for me. I'm trying to implement IRetryAnalyzer from testNG, to re run the test cases that failed.

And this is what I've done, but can't make it work. Note all this code I've copied form the internet.

```
public class Retry implements IRetryAnalyzer {

private int retryCount = 0;
private int maxRetryCount = 2;

@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {

    if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
        System.out.println("Entre");
        retryCount++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Here is my test method were it should fail and re run the test.

```
@Parameters({ "nombrePlan", "nombreBuild", "nomTL_verificacionUIHomePageIssuer" })
@Test(retryAnalyzer = Retry.class)
  public void verificacionUIHomePageIssuer(String nombrePlan, String nombreBuild, String nomTL_verificacionUIHomePageIssuer) throws Exception {
    HomePageIssuer homePage = new HomePageIssuer(driver);
    //Assert.assertTrue(homePage.validacionLogin(), homePage.getError());
    Assert.assertTrue(false);
}
```

The thing is that when I run it doesn't work the driver closes and the test never starts again. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any exception?  How are parameter values being set.  I used the exact same code as yours except the HomePageIssuer init and it retried.  What version of testng are you on?

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer exception, because when the test finishes, the driver instance is closed, so when it tries to re run the test, it doesn't instantiate a new driver. And I can't figure out how to make it instantiate a new driver.

Comment: Im on the 6.3.1 testng version. Could it be a version error ?

Comment: Where are you initializing the driver?

Comment: All my testcases extend from BaseTestCase, that is were I initialize my WebDriver Instance, but for some reason then the Test fails, it doesn't call my BeforeTest annotation.

Comment: BeforeTest will only be called once for your entire <test> tag.  Try using @beforemethod, but then this would init after every testcase.

Comment: Thanks very much that was the problem the annotation, i didnt realize is was using BeforeTest when i should have been using BeforeMethod.

Comment: Shall I mark this as an answer then for future use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, @BeforeTest was being used for driver initalization and hence Retry wasn't invoking it again.

BeforeTest will only be called once for your entire  tag. Try using @beforemethod, but then this would init after every testcase.